# I receive empty allure report in GitHUb actions CI. Locally everything works

Tags: allure

I receive empty allure report in GitHUb actions CI. Locally everything works. (allure report is generated successfully). All tests are passed. I use WebDriverIO
I use:

- name: Archive Test Results
  if: always()
  shell: bash
  run: npm run generate:report
  allure generate --clean --format html -o allure-report
  ls -l allure-report
  npm run archive:results

  - name: Upload Test Results
    uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
    with:
    name: e2e
    path: allure-report/**

Please, help, what I miss?

Maybe i miss some command